# How to save token in an environment variable using curl and jq from the terminal

Tags: curl, cmd, jq

I am running this command

```
set TOKEN = `curl -d '{"email":"some@gmail.com","password":"password"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:80/auth  | jq -r ".token"`
```

from a course I am taking and I keep on getting this error and honestly, I have failed to find a solution that solves it so I am asking for your help.

The error;

> jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?) at , line 1:
>   .token
>   jq: 1 compile error

Comment: Please check this out: https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ#windows

Comment: Your question is not a specific programming issue with your provided code, it is instead, "how do I use a specific command within a particular shell on a specific platform". General questions about how to use a tool or command, are off topic on StackOverflow, please delete your question and research the command syntax for your target platform yourself.

Comment: The `cmd` tag implies Microsoft Windows. Are you running this on Microsoft Windows? From where did you get the `curl` command? Likewise, what is your source of the `jq` command?

Comment: @lit, I am doing this in the cmd,  have jq installed and I want to save the output from the request in variable and set it as an environment variable. The error message seems to be from jq at the point `| jq -r '.token'`. For the Origin, this is how I am trying to do it and I'm sure it's not from the curl bit of this thread set TOKEN=`curl -d '{"email":"email@gmail.com","password":"password"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:80/auth  | jq -r '.token'`

Comment: @lit `curl` is installed with windows 10 by default.

Comment: I think the `\`` quote is not finished correctly

Comment: @dan1st - Yes, I see curl in my System32 directory. Not sure how it got there.

Comment: @muwongenicholus - The use of GRAVE ACCENT (backtick) leads me to think that this line came from a UNIX/Linux shell comand script. Windows cmd scripts would not put a SPACE character around the EQUALS character. What do you think will be the result of executing this line?

Comment: @dan1st, I double-checked and the backticks are correctly finished

Comment: @lit, there are no white spaces around the equal signs and the result would be a JWT Token.

Comment: @muwongenicholus - Windows does -not- use backticks to execute a command. Even on UNIX/Linux, backticks are deprecated in favor of $(). Windows cmd.exe can put the text result of a command into a variable using a `FOR` loop. Yeah, crazy stuff. See the output of `FOR /?` for additional information.

Comment: To fix the jq part, use `jq -r .token` without any quotes. But the single quotes around the curl payload look wrong (Windows doesn't do single quotes) and the backticks look wrong too (as mentioned several times in other comments).